# How to change value of UI items in Thread?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

I need to create C# application, which can change values of UI items in different threads. So, how can I do it? I try to create simple Thread object, and change TextView text in it, but I have got exception. How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a WinForms application you should use the [Invoke/BeginInvoke](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) method to marshal the call on the UI thread. And if you are using WPF/Silverlight you should use the [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) method.

Comment: I use Invoke(new MethodInvoker(enctyptThread)). But my UI is frozen, and it is not good solution

Comment: @user1023177, where are you using this? Normally this should be done from the callback which executes on the background thread.

Comment: I have callback event (button1_click) - I execute new MethodInvoker(enctyptThread) here.

Comment: @user1023177, you should execute this in a new thread, not inside click event handlers. Click event handlers run on the UI thread. You should start a new thread there.

Comment: Please, can you create a new post with sample of code? It is very important for me, thank you.

Comment: @user1023177, there are many examples out there. Suffice to search and read a little: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Threading.aspx The article I have posted in my answer also contains examples. Don't hesitate to ask if you encounter some problems when you try to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) to do it.

Comment: I use Invoke(new MethodInvoker(enctyptThread)). But my UI is frozen, and it is not good solution